# Disable weak SSL protocols on Windows Server 2016

Tags: ssl, iis, windows-server-2016

We have tried to disable weak SSL/TLS protocols on a windows 2016 server by setting the corresonding registry keys as suggested here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/tls/tls-registry-settings#tls-10

We have created the following DWORDs:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
```

After a restart of the server a scan like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html still reports that the server supports TLS 1.0 and 1.1. We have cleared the scan cache after the change, so it shouldn't be a cached result. I also get a 200 OK response by

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://MyServer -SslProtocol Tls
```

If I use a tool like IISCrypto it reports that the protocols are disabled.

Any ideas regarding why these protocols are not being disabled by the registry keys above are very welcome!

Comment: Exactly what did you disable and enable in IIS Crypto?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I didn't disable anything in IISCrypto, I just noticed the protocols corresponding to the registry keys above were disabled.

Comment: I've now also disabled the client protocols, no change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your server directly exposed to the internet?  It's not a common practice anymore.  Usually there is a load balancer or reverse proxy in front of it these days.  If there is, that's what the SSL labs scan is hitting and that's where you need to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1.